# Add line near TextView

Tags: android, textview, line

I would like to add a line near a textView like the img below in android:

[line near text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNcTw.jpg)

here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothSwitch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Bluetooth"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bluetoothSwitch"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:dividerPadding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bluetoothSwitch"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Show Paired Device"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="PAIRED DEVICE: "
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my app screen:

[where a would like to add line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBAkJ.jpg)

i took this screenshot from my samsung settings. i would add the line near the textview "paired device".
i read to use view but i can't do it.
Can someone help me?
thank you all

Comment: use a `<View />` with a height of `1dp` and whatever other attributes like color etc.. wrap the `Textview` and `View` in a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and will be always aligned to textview

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Wifi Cellular"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#636363"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

sample work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Text"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.7dp"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Change the background colour of view to any colour and change it's height accordingly and place marginLeft also if needed.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
```